# error when trying to remove Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE

Tags: android, android-activity

I work with a library that runs the camera. need to make sure that the camera is working in full screen. To do this, write so

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Initialize and start the bar code recognition.
        initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning();
    }



public void initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning() {
            // Switch to full screen.
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            // We instantiate the automatically adjusting barcode picker that will
            // choose the correct picker to instantiate. Be aware that this picker
            // should only be instantiated if the picker is shown full screen as the
            // legacy picker will rotate the orientation and not properly work in
            // non-fullscreen.
            ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker picker = new ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker(
                    this, sScanditSdkAppKey, ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

            // Add both views to activity, with the scan GUI on top.
            setContentView(picker);
            mBarcodePicker = picker;

            // Register listener, in order to be notified about relevant events
            // (e.g. a successfully scanned bar code).
            mBarcodePicker.getOverlayView().addListener(this);

            // Show a search bar in the scan user interface.
            mBarcodePicker.getOverlayView().showSearchBar(true);
        }
```

and get an error

```
02-03 16:08:59.089    6890-6890/com.skip.client.customer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.skip.client.customer, PID: 6890
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skip.client.customer/com.skip.client.customer.activities.ScanActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:249)
            at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3371)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.supportRequestWindowFeature(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:460)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportRequestWindowFeature(ActionBarActivity.java:194)
            at com.skip.client.customer.activities.ScanActivity.initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning(ScanActivity.java:53)
            at com.skip.client.customer.activities.ScanActivity.onCreate(ScanActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

error on the line

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

If I call this line before the method super all works

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Initialize and start the bar code recognition.
        initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning();
    }
```

but you can not do? am I right?

Comment: call  initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning(); before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling `supportRequestWindowFeature` before `super.onCreate` then no need to call it again inside `initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning` method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Initialize and start the bar code recognition.
        initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning();
    }
public void initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning() {
 .....
}
```

Comment: I realized that govoritt error. question - whether to call methods apered super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); ???

Comment: @PavelPetrashov: means ?? i'm not getting you

Comment: I always thought that writing code before the method super () is wrong

Comment: @PavelPetrashov: yes you are right when we want to call super class  constructor then `super` should be first statement but in `onCreate` method you are calling `onCreate` method from super calling which is Activity using `super.onCreate`